# Understanding a specific usage of the "super" keyword in Rust

Tags: rust

I understand that `super` lets you access the "parent" scope, but I stumbled upon this code from [`std::io`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b1363a73ede57ae595f3a1be2bb75d308ba4f7f6/src/libstd/io/util.rs#L49) and I'm not sure how it works.

```
pub fn copy<R: ?Sized, W: ?Sized>(reader: &mut R, writer: &mut W) -> io::Result<u64>
    where R: Read, W: Write
{
    let mut buf = [0; super::DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE];
    let mut written = 0;
    loop {
        let len = match reader.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(0) => return Ok(written),
            Ok(len) => len,
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        };
        writer.write_all(&buf[..len])?;
        written += len as u64;
    }
}
```

How does it access `super::DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE`? I can see it is declared in `sys_common::io`, but I can't see how this module can be the `util` module's parent though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source for the function [`copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/std/io/util.rs.html#46-61) is located in the [`util`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/std/io/util.rs.html) module that is imported by [`io`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/libstd/io)'s module file, [`mod.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/io/mod.rs). Since `DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE` is [defined](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L293) in `mod.rs`, you need to access it via `super` from `util.rs`.

Comment: Hmmm - thanks, so if I write `use std::io::util::copy;` is it imported through `mod.rs`, perhaps my problem is with not understanding how imports are resolved.

Comment: @opensourcegeek You should probably head back to The Book on [multiple file crates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#multiple-file-crates).

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missed a definition, if you check out [`std/io/mod.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b1363a73ede57ae595f3a1be2bb75d308ba4f7f6/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#287) you'll see:

```
const DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE: usize = 8 * 1024;
```

That's all.